# Do I need to declare __declspec(dllexport) for a class that is only passed to a templated function?

Tags: c++, windows, class, dllexport

I have a dll that contains some generator functions for classes provided in the dll as well as the classes itself. So lets say in the dll there is

```
class Foo;
```

The dll provides a method to create `Foo` (and other) objects

```
template<class T>
void MyDll::createObj()
```

that can create some `Foo` objects that only exist inside the dll. They are never accessed from outside the dll.

Do I still need to add `__declspec(dllexport)` to the `Foo` class?
Because when I would implement it without templates, as long as the class is not used anywhere else I could just have the methods

```
void createFooObj();
void createBarObj();
```

and so on without the export.

Comment: If you don't use Foo outside the DLL then why would you need to mark it as dllexport?

Comment: because I want to use the templated createObj<>() function from outside which will create an instance inside the dll.

Comment: The template is defined in the header file, right?

Comment: yes, the template is in the header